# Django Invalid http_host

Tags: python, django

I am trying to host a django server over lan, but I keep getting:

> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '192.168.1.9:8000'. You may need to add '192.168.1.9' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

The website functions when I use local host site. Both local host and my local ip are set as allowed hosts in my settings file.

I am running the server using
`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

**Settings**

```py
import os

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "**************"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['198.168.1.9', 'localhost', '192.168.1.1', '0.0.0.0', ]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: Can you post your settings file? Have you tried rebooting the server after the change?

Comment: Ok I added it. Also I did reboot.

Comment: There should be no way you could be getting that error with the supplied configuration. Are you sure the instance you're running is using that settings file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way you posted here you have a typo on your ip `198.168.1.9` instead of `192.168.1.9`, change `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to this:

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.1.9', 'localhost', '192.168.1.1', '0.0.0.0', ]
```

Comment: @Nico Please, consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/526214)